# How can I validate a Yup array in React-hook-form with a required second date?

Tags: typescript, schema, react-hook-form, yup, next.js13

My Array attribute is like this,

Selected_date : [ , ]

Here, selected-date is a range of date i.e startDate and EndDate and both of them will be stored in selected_date[0] and selected_date[1] respectively.

My validation should throw an error only if the 2nd date is not selected and should not throw any error when the field is empty or both the dates are selected.

I tried Array().min(2).required("Second Date is required") but didn't worked out for me..

[enter image description here][1]

Here the same field Completion_date will contain 2 array elements which is the source date and the destination date if the source date is selected and the destination date is left as null, i need a warning saying the 2nd date is empyu.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVE3b.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I validate the dates in my `yup` object in this way and it works for me:

```
eventDates: yup
.array()
.length(2)
.required('Event dates are required')
.of(yup.date())
```